# convert For syntax to a faster way in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have below code and I want to convert it to a faster way but I don't how I can convert For syntax to a faster way in Matlab.
If user count is 5 and item count is 2 and time count is 4, I want to create this matrix:
    1  1  1
    1  1  2
    1  1  3
    1  1  4
    1  2  1
    1  2  2
    1  2  3
    1  2  4
    2  1  1
    2  1  2
    2  1  3
    2  1  4
...

```
result=zeros(userCount*itemCount*timeCount,4);
j=0;
for i=1:userCount
     result(j*itemCount*timeCount+1:j*itemCount*timeCount+itemCount*timeCount,1)=ones(itemCount*timeCount,1)*i;
     j=j+1;
end
j=0;
h=1;
for i=1:userCount*itemCount
    result(j*timeCount+1:j*timeCount+timeCount,2)=ones(timeCount,1)*(h);
    j=j+1;
    h=h+1;
    if h>itemCount
           h=1;
     end
 end
j=0;
for i=1:userCount*itemCount
     result(j*timeCount+1:j*timeCount+timeCount,3)=1:timeCount;
     j=j+1;
end
for i=1:size(subs,1)
     f=(result(:,1)==subs(i,1)& result(:,2)==subs(i,2));
     result(f,:)=[];
 end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing is to enumerate permutations for three independent linear sets.  One way to achieve this would be to use [`ndgrid`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html) and unroll each output into a single vector:

```
userCount = 5; itemCount = 2; timeCount = 4;
[X,Y,Z] = ndgrid(1:timeCount,1:itemCount,1:userCount);
result = [Z(:) Y(:) X(:)];
```

We get:

```
result =

     1     1     1
     1     1     2
     1     1     3
     1     1     4
     1     2     1
     1     2     2
     1     2     3
     1     2     4
     2     1     1
     2     1     2
     2     1     3
     2     1     4
     2     2     1
     2     2     2
     2     2     3
     2     2     4
     3     1     1
     3     1     2
     3     1     3
     3     1     4
     3     2     1
     3     2     2
     3     2     3
     3     2     4
     4     1     1
     4     1     2
     4     1     3
     4     1     4
     4     2     1
     4     2     2
     4     2     3
     4     2     4
     5     1     1
     5     1     2
     5     1     3
     5     1     4
     5     2     1
     5     2     2
     5     2     3
     5     2     4
```